# TWIG - Split variable after certain amount of characters

Tags: variables, split, set, twig

I don't want to use Javascript, because I think it's possible with the code of Twig.

**My problem:**
I have a variable: `{{ var.content }}`, which I want to split after +-720 characters into an other variable. I know `{{ var.content | length }}` gives me the number of characters.

Ideally the solution would be something with `{% set (...) %}` so I get something like:

- `{{ var.content1 }}` for the first 720 characters
- `{{ var.content2 }}` for the remaining text/characters

Is this possible with Twig, if yes, does somebody know how?

Comment: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/slice.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the twig filter split

```
{% set bar = var.content|split('', 720) %}
{{ bar[0] }}
```

**EDIT**
I edited this solution according to the comments on OP and this answer:

The preceding solution will give you an array filled by chunks of 720 max length strings

The following solution will give you as OP wanted, 2 elements, first 720 length, second with the remaining chars

```
{% set bar = [var.content|slice(0,720), var.content|slice(720, var.content|length)] %}
```

Comment: According to the [Twig documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/split.html) it will return an array with 720 elements.

Comment: Last part of the doc "If the delimiter is an empty string, then value will be split by equal chunks. Length is set by the limit argument (one character by default)."

Comment: Ok I see, I wasn't sure if the delimiter has to be empty or missing. What if the string has more than 1440 characters, will it create 3 strings?

Comment: Yes, the result will be an array sized 3, with 3 elements. The first and the second will have a fixed length of 720, the third will have between 1 and 719

Comment: The OP wants only two variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
{% set content1 = var.content|slice(0, 720) %}
{% set content2 = var.content|slice(720) %}
```